# Why oil is offered to Lord Hanuman on Saturday?

Tags: temple, hanuman, prayer

If you visit Hanuman temple especially on Saturdays, we see a number of devotees offer oil (especially gingili oil).
Why oil is offered to Lord Hanuman

Comment: One reason might be that oil is required to be mixed in Sindoor...and the mixture is then applied on Hanuman idol regularly..so people offer Sindoor and/or Oil and/or mixture of sindoor-oil....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people offer mustard oil to Lord Shani?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/736/why-do-people-offer-mustard-oil-to-lord-shani)

Comment: Gingili oil is offered to Hanuman for lighting the lamps. By offering oil, your known and unknown sins will slowly vanish.

Comment: @YDS Sindoor is mixed with butter not with gingili oil.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan NO...in our side it's mixed with oil...

Answer (score 3):

Black sesame or Til seeds are one of the materials signified by Saneeshwara ( Lord Saturn). Gingelly oil derived from sesame seeds are therefore used to burn oil lamps on Saturday to propitiate Saneeshwara, especially if the devotee is having sade-sati.This is a wide practice in southern India, called Neeranjanam lamp for Saneeshwara. Due to reasons given in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/736/why-do-people-offer-mustard-oil-to-lord-shani?rq=1), Lord Hanuman alleviates the trouble of devotees having bad effects of Saneeshwara / sade-sati. This would be basis of offering gingelly oil to Hanuman on Saturday. Again these are local practices based on local fables ( desa kala pramanas) and may probably have no scriptural basis.